# JSTree, Add child node is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I am using JSTree for the first time, trying to add a child node to an existing node but it is not working so far.
I know this topic have been discussed many times but I tried a lot of suggestions and still doesn't work out.

here is a piece of code

```js
$('#jstree_div').jstree();
var ElemSelected=$("#jstree_div").jstree(true).get_selected(true);
var position = 'inside';
var childNode = { state: "open", data: "Child Node" };

$('#jstree_div').jstree("create_node", ElemSelected, position, newNode, false, false);
```

```html
<div id='jstree_div'>
  <ul>
     <li id='racine' data-jstree={'opened':true,'selected':true}>
       <a id='j2_6_anchor' class='jstree-clicked' href='#'></a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know what I am missing, I will be greatfull if you can help me with this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var tree = $('#jstree_div').jstree({core:{
 check_callback : true
}});
```

you need to add "check_callback : true" to be able create a new node

check the function parameters on theirs documentation -->
[https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node([par, node, pos, callback, is_loaded])](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node([par,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded]))

```js
var tree = $('#jstree_div').jstree({core:{
 check_callback : true
}});

var ElemSelected=$("#jstree_div").jstree(true).get_selected(true);
var position = 'inside';
var childNode = { state: "open", data: "Child Node" ,text:"Child Node" };

$('#jstree_div').jstree("create_node",null, childNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.jstree/3.3.1/jstree.js"></script>
<div id='jstree_div'>
  <ul>
     <li id='racine' data-jstree={'opened':true,'selected':true}>
       <a id='j2_6_anchor' class='jstree-clicked' href='#'></a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is working now  the problem was mainly caused by the check_callback : true